# Design direction for multiple format parsing

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am writing an app to parse lines in a text file. The problem is that I need to be able to load different routines depending on a variable set at run-time. I can not change the format of the incoming file.

```
int intFormat = 1; //Loaded from INI file

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) {
    myFileConverstion *myFC;
    switch(intFormat) {
        case 1:
            myFC = new FileConverstionCompanyA(); 
        case 2:
            myFC = new FileConverstionCompanyB();
    }
    myFileConverstion->Execute("fileName");
}
```

Within `->Execute()`, I would be calling `private` (or `protected`) methods to do the parsing. There are some of the methods that could be used across all formats, too.

What would be the best OOP way to do this?

- Create a virtual object i.e: `myFileConverstion`? Then inherit from that for the `CompanyA`, `B`, `C`, etc.
- write `myFileConverstion` with all the common methods (private/protected) and a virtual `Execute()`. Then just change the `Execute()` internals for the various "companies"?

I'm looking for some guidance.

Haven't really tried anything yet, I'm in the planning stage.

Comment: Make `FileConverstionCompanyA` and `FileConverstionCompanyB` inherited the same class, and use `Base* myFC`

Comment: Regarding the snippet of code you've shown, what happens if `intFormat` is something other than `1` or `2`? Also watch out for fall-through in C++ switch statements.

Comment: `myFileConverstion->Execute` (with *t*?) should be `myFC->Execute`. Otherwise it does not make sense. Perhaps even move the `switch case` into its own function (= factory function). Never use blank `new` statements in user code. Use `make_unique` instead. In your code, the `FileConverstionCompanyA` and `FileConverstionCompanyB` and `myFileConverstion` need `virtual` `Execute` member functions and virtual constructors. I would recommend for a more consistent casing like classes starting with an upper-case letter, variables with a lower-case letter.

Comment: @Chris: The code snippet was just quick and dirty, to get the idea across.

Comment: @Sebastin: You are right, I just miss typed :(

Answer (score 2):

There would also be the possibility to realize the whole thing with std:.function by inserting them into some kind of lookup map. Here is some example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class FileConverter
{
    using convert_engine_t = std::function< bool( const std::string& ) >;
    std::unordered_map< size_t, convert_engine_t > engines;
    convert_engine_t *activeEngine { nullptr };
public:
    template < class T >
    auto addEngine( size_t id, T && routine ) -> void
    {
        engines.emplace( id, std::forward< T >( routine ) );
    }

    auto setActiveEngine( size_t id ) -> bool
    {
        const auto iterFound = engines.find( id );

        if ( iterFound == engines.end() )
            return false;

        activeEngine = &iterFound->second;
        return true;
    }

    auto convert( const std::string fileName ) -> bool
    {
        if ( !activeEngine || !( *activeEngine ) )
            return false;

        return ( *activeEngine )( fileName );
    }
};

int main()
{
    struct MyConvertingEngineA
    {
        auto operator()( const auto& fn ) {
           std::cout << "Doing A" << std::endl; return true;
        }
    };

    auto myConvertingEngineB = []( const auto& fn ) {
        std::cout << "Doing B" << std::endl; return true;
    };

    FileConverter myFC;
    myFC.addEngine( 1, MyConvertingEngineA() );
    myFC.addEngine( 2, std::move( myConvertingEngineB ) );
    myFC.addEngine( 8, []( const auto& fn ){ std::cout << "Doing C" << std::endl; return true; } );

    myFC.setActiveEngine( 1 );
    myFC.convert( "MyFileA1" );
    myFC.convert( "MyFileA2" );

    myFC.setActiveEngine( 2 );
    myFC.convert( "MyFileB" );

    myFC.setActiveEngine( 8 );
    myFC.convert( "MyFileC" );

    myFC.setActiveEngine( 7 ); // Will fail, old engine will remain active
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
Doing A
Doing A
Doing B
Doing C

**A few explanations about the code:**
The addEngine function uses templates with a forwarding reference and
perfect forwarding to provide the widest possible interface.
Engines are copied or moved here, depending on the type of reference passing. The engines are passed in form of "callable objects".
Different types like functors or lambdas can be added.
Even (as in the example) generic lambdas can be passed (auto parameter) as long as the function signature of of std::function is fulfilled.
This saves another redundant specification of the string type.
If you have large and complex engines, use a separate class instead of a lambda to keep the local scope small

Shared parser-functionality could also be passed to the respective engines via smart pointer if you don't want to have any inheritance.

```
    class EngineA
    {
        std::shared_ptr< ParserCore > parserCore;
    public:
        EngineA( std::shared_ptr< ParserCore > parserCoreParam ) : 
            parserCore( std::move( parserCoreParam ) ) 
        {}
        
        auto operator()( const auto& fn ) {
           std::cout << "Doing A" << std::endl; return true;
           // -> parserCore->helperFuncForABC() ....;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply. However, I don't need the ability to randomly select an "engine".  In the app configuration, the user will be selecting a "company format" that would be used every time they run the conversation.

Comment: I was thinking that in the constructor for the form that I would use the switch/case to select the correct parser object.

Comment: My code example is only one of many possible ways to solve this task. If you like a solution with inheritance better or you are still missing things feel free to refine the task.